# Once event was reported to Universal Analytics - is there any way to remove or modify it?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Suppose an event was reported to Google Analytics using their API. Once reported, is there any way to remove or modify the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's no way to delete or modify historical data - once it's in there, it stays there. However, you can try to use filters to filter the data you want "removed". For example, to exclude an event, you can create an Exclude filter to filter your event by category, action, or label.